# I was used WP PDF Generator wordpress plugin to generate pdf but i want to remove header and footer from pdf, how can i do this?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using WP PDF Generator word-press plugin, this is work completely, but i want to generate PDF of particular portion of word-press page, so any one help me how can i do this?

Comment: have you some code

Comment: you have to modify the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Go in plugin and make changes in wp_objects_pdf.php file it's will help to eliminate the header and footer.

Comment: Tnxs, I was checked, but i can't find anything, i think it's export PDF through URL, so we can not remove header and footer, If you have a any idea then please help me.

Comment: Like any other plugin or custom code so i can generate PDF

Comment: what is in your header and footer

Comment: it is website header and footer, not PDF header and footer, and i want to remove website header and footer in generated PDF

Comment: look in pdf genratar page string which is create with your code and using strpos eluminate it

Comment: Tnxs, but i am not generate pdf through custom code, but generate through wordpress plugin, and i was checked this plugin generate pdf through URL, so i think it is not possible to remove header and footer, so you have any other idea to how to generate pdf throgh wordpress plugin or excluding header and footer?